# Iterating over a c++ macro "list" to generate code

Tags: c++, macros

I'd like to write some c++ macro code to convert:

```
#define FRUITS Apple Banana Plum
EXPAND(FRUITS)
```

into:

```
void eat(Apple& instanceApple);
void eat(Banana& instanceBanana);
void eat(Plum& instancePlum);
```

Is it possible to write an EXPAND() function to accomplish my goal?

I realize this doesn't look like good programming practice, but I have to link to a 3rd-party library with a specific interface, and the ability to do this will allow me to avoid large repetitive code blocks within my own code.

EDIT: changed my toy example slightly.

Comment: Why would you want to obfuscate your code like that?

Comment: My toy example doesn't show it, but I also will need code of the form "void eatFruit(Apple apple); void eatFruit(Banana banana)", etc. When a new fruit is added, I don't want to have to edit multiple spots in the code. Templating so I have "void eat<Fruit>(Fruit f)" would of course be best but the interface of the 3rd-party library I'm linking against won't allow this.

Comment: If you're just tyring to allocate the default value for each, than an std::tuple<Apple,Bannana,Plum> might work well for you. Even better in C++14 with `template T& tuple::get<T>`.

Comment: Make a fruit base class and derive specific fruits from it. Then you only need one function that takes a reference to fruit.

Comment: @NeilKirk The declarations of these fruits live in 3rd-party code that I cannot modify. They do not all inherit from the same base class in that code-base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not saying this does much for readability, but it does what you want using Boost.Preprocessor:

```
#define DECLARE_VAR(r, data, type) type BOOST_PP_CAT(instance,type);
#define EXPAND(seq) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECLARE_VAR,,seq)
```

Now you can define your list of fruits as follows:

```
#define FRUITS (Apple)(Banana)(Plum)
```

And then you can use `EXPAND(FRUITS)` to generate the variable declarations. For a full example, [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f24ad61d8fb8f95d).

Per request, the same technique used to print one fruit per line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define PER_LINE(r, data, type) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(type) "\n"
#define EXPAND(seq) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(PER_LINE,,seq)

#define FRUITS (Apple)(Banana)(Plum)

int main() {
    std::cout << EXPAND(FRUITS);
}
```

Comment: If you need to do this then 90% sure something is very wrong with the program design.

Comment: @NeilKirk, Yeah, though I'd need more information to say how to fix it. Considering the separate types, a template can probably work wonders.

Comment: @NeilKirk The 3rd-party library goes to great extremes to avoid incurring runtime costs of virtual functions and polymorphism, as this is an extremely performance-critical application. With that said, they are working on changes to improve usability in exchange for incurring a slight performance hit. The current situation is ugly.

Comment: @David You must me making one heck of a grocery app ;)

Comment: @David, If you give some kind of sample that you'd like to compile (a separate test from your real code), it might be possible to do it better. I'm just not sure what you're *doing* with these variables.

Comment: @chris Your example looks perfect. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: May you enhance the sample to also print some text e.g. `Apple\nBanana\nPlum\n`, please?   It will be easier to understand for a beginner like me.  Thank.

Comment: @javaLover, I don't clearly see how this helps a beginner. There is almost assuredly a better way to do what you want that doesn't involve macros and a second example doesn't go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have time to explain, but I just made this:

```
struct A
{
  int i;
  A(){i=1;}
  void quack() {std::cout << "A" << i << std::endl;}
};

struct B
{
  int i;
  B(){i=2;}
  void quack() {std::cout << "B" << i << std::endl;}
};
struct C
{
  int i;
  C(){i=3;}
  void quack() {std::cout << "C" << i << std::endl;}
};

#include <tuple>
std::tuple<A,B,C> tupl;


struct quacker
{
  template <typename T>
void operator()(T& t)
{
  t.quack();
}
};

template <typename Q,std::size_t index, typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<
index < sizeof...(Ts) >::type foo_helper(Q q,std::tuple<Ts...>& ts)
{
  q(std::get<index>(ts));
  foo_helper<Q,index+1,Ts...>(q,ts);
}
template <typename Q,std::size_t index, typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<
index >= sizeof...(Ts) >::type foo_helper(Q q,std::tuple<Ts...>& ts)
{

}

template <typename Q, typename... Ts>
void foo(Q q,std::tuple<Ts...> ts)
{
  foo_helper<Q,0,Ts...>(q,ts);
}





int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

  foo(quacker(),tupl);
}
```